# How to write a multi thread perl script to write a log file?

Tags: multithreading, perl

The log file need to be updated every now and then.The problem here is if i use multi thread to write a same log file i could see some lines are incorrect.

```
my $date_string = strftime "%Y%m%d\_%H\_%M\_%S",localtime;

open(LOG,"+>","log\_$date_string.log")or die "cant open the file";


for ($count = 1; $count <=$thread_count ; $count++) 
{
    my $thread = threads->new(\&process);
    push(@threads,$thread);        

}

foreach (@threads) 
{
   $_->join;
}
close LOG;

sub process
{  ......
   ......
   print LOG "$datestring"."\|$process_id\|$host\|$port\|input\|Processing $filename\|\n";
}
```

For the above code iam getting output like this:

```
2014-05-20 12:12:46|19903|172.16.7.109|2000|input|Processing /opt/search_command/_13668.out|
2014-05-20 12:12:47|19903|172.16.7.109|2000|search|Processing /opt/search_command/_13668.out|0.940|
5-20 12:12:46|19903|172.16.7.109|2000|input|Processing /opt/search_command/_11061.out|
2014-05-20 12:12:47|19903|172.16.7.109|2000|search|Processing /opt/search_command/_11061.out|0.952|
```

If you see the third line date is not printed properly

I need a solution on how to log the status in log file using multi thread in perl.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock the file before writing, and release lock after it.

```
sub process {  
   lock(\*LOG);
   print LOG ..
   unlock(\*LOG);
}


use Fcntl qw(:flock SEEK_END);

sub lock {
  my ($fh) = @_;
  flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die $!;
  seek($fh, 0, SEEK_END) or die $!;
}
sub unlock {
  my ($fh) = @_;
  flock($fh, LOCK_UN) or die $!;
}
```

Comment: What if i write a log in more place,and i need to use lock everytime it would slow up the process i suggest

Comment: @Venkatesan you can benchmark it, but no significant slowdown should occur if you release lock immediately after printing to file.

Comment: You are right it doesnt take any extra time to execute and can you explain me why seek is used here

Comment: @Venkatesan file pointer should be moved to the end of file since concurrent threads are constantly writing to it.